# How to dynamically add waypoints

Tags: javascript, angular, agm-map

I wonder is it possible to dynamically add waypoints, then update the direction without refreshing the page?

HTML

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-direction #vc [renderOptions]="renderOptions"  (onChange)="onChange($event)" [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [waypoints]="waypoints" #route (onChange)="check($event)"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

TS

```
newPoint(event) {
const lattitude = event.geometry.location.lat();
const longitude = event.geometry.location.lng();
const point = {
  name: event.formatted_address,
  lattitude,
  longitude
};
this.checkpoints.push(point)
this.waypoints.push({ location: { lat: lattitude, lng: longitude } });
```

}

Comment: Not sure what is the complexity here. In the component we can update the value for 'waypoints' and then your child component will be reloaded without reloading of the whole page

Comment: nothing happens, when i push new point to array of waypoints

Comment: Are you using onPush change detection strategy in your component? If it's so, you need to do this.cd.detectChanges() after updating the value.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you expand a little bit on what you said about it?

Comment: Can you also share your component where you are updating the waypoints value